# How to add a second vAxis on the right to a Google Combo Chart and assign a series to it in icCube reporting v6?

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

I can add a second vAxis under Axes Configuration, but it doesn't display anywhere in the chart. How can I display a second axis on the right side and assign a series to it?